# Creating a listener on a list for changes

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I have a dart object which contains a list.  Simply put:

```
class Test extends PolymerElement{
  List list = [];

  addTask(item){
    list.add(item);
  }
}
```

and I wanted to implement a listener on that list in another object:

```
class listenerClass extends PolymerElement {
  Test get _data => $['Object'];
}
```

So the object is retrieved from the dom withthe getter.

Is there a way to observe a change in the parent?  I tried the following:

```
@Observe("_data.list")
dataListChanged(_,__){
  var item = _data.list.last;
  //do magic with item.
}
```

I have the underscore because it is private and isnt exposed to Dom or anything... but the list itself isnt a property so it doesnt notify or anything.

I was hoping there was a way to do some sort of listener for it though.

My desired endstate is that I want to fire a function in the parent whenever an item is added to the list, with only the reference to the child object as defined above.  Even though this _data is populated by way of Polymer, Since this isnt touching properties at all, the answer may likely just be Pure dart.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how polymer works. Polymer framework has no way to know you have defined a getter in your class and emit the right notification.

You should add `notify` to the `list` property of `Test` and bind that to a property in `listenerClass`. Then observe that variable.

But probably you will have better luck with `ObservableList` and using [autonotify](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/autonotify_observe) for a simpler way to use observability with polymer-dart projects.